# How to prevent syslog message popping in a ssh session without affect other sessions?

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, syslog, console

i have a machine(RHEL 5.2) which receives syslog message from remote machines. And now it keeps popping message from remote machine in a ssh shell, which is annoying when i want to do something on it.

messages are like this:

> Message from syslogd@ at Thu Jul 17 18:05:45 2014 ...
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (a number seems representing time): blahblah

i found this line in /etc/syslog.conf file:

> kern.*                                                  /dev/console

the problem is that i don't want to disable it, i only want to disable this temporarily for my current ssh session

i have tried 'dmesg -n1' but it does not works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/dev/console is not your current session, it is the server console (the screen you see when attaching a monitor).

What you see in your terminal are the emergency messages. I am not sure if you can restrict these messages per terminal, but you can restrict them to be sent only to specific users. A quick Google search revealed [this](http://www.softpanorama.org/Logs/syslog.shtml) link to be useful and it shows how to do it.

Comment: well, after some search i found that it seems that there is no way to achieve my goal, nor can i separate remote log from local's. but still thanks for your information

Comment: Try "dmesg -n 0" and see if it does what you want...